# SPARQL select from namespace

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki

It's easy to select all statements from fuseki with a query like:

```
SELECT * { ?s  ?o  ?z}
```

but how to obtain all statements from a certain namespace prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by testing the URI: if "from a certain namespace prefix" you want the subjects in the namespace: for `?s`:

```sql
PREFIX ns: <....>
SELECT * {
 ?s  ?o  ?z
 FILTER (isURI(?s) && STRSTARTS(str(?s), str(ns:) ) )
}
```